# Text file in php how processes it

Tags: php

i have text file as this way :

```
Name     : Apache2.2
State    : Running
Name     : Axxx
State    : Running
Name     : Azzzz
State    : Running
Name     : Apddd
State    : Running

The End Of part one 
Name     : Apache2.2
State    : Running
Name     : Apache2.2
State    : Running
The End Of Part 2
```

and i want to return text from first until

> "The End Of part one"

only and avoid the text after that How can i do it ?

Comment: **_return text from first until "The End Of part one" only and avoid the text after that_** ! So you want to print "The End Of part one" ? `echo('The End Of part one');`

Comment: No , i need from the start of text untill The End Of part one

Comment: @Eng.D I have written an answer. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text= file_get_contents("test.txt"); 
//Fetch the file

echo $text = substr($text, 0, strpos($text, "one")+5);
//echo out the text
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: still not fetch what i need, it's given me all text !!

Comment: @Eng.D I have updated the answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileHandle = fopen("yourFile.txt", "r");
$wantedLines = [];
if ($fileHandle) {
    while (($line = fgets($fileHandle)) !== false) {
        if(strpos($line, "The End Of part one") >= 0)
            break;
        $wantedLines[] = $line;           
    }
    return $wantedLines;
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

in this way, you don't load the entire file in RAM.